# Any ways to improve this regex oneliner?

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I have a lot of video files with the following syntax:

```
TV.Show.Title.SXEY.Episode.Title.1080p.Uploader.mkv
```

where `SXEY` is not constant. `X` and `Y` are numbers depending on the file. I would like to rename them to

```
TV Show Title - SXEY - Episode Title.mkv
```

In order to do that I use the `rename` command as the following oneliner:

```
rename 's/\./\ -\ /;s/\./\ -\ /;s/\.(?!mkv)/\ /g;s/1080p.*(?=\.mkv)//g' *.mkv
```

The command first transforms the first two dots into `␣-␣`, then transforms all the other dots into whitespaces and finally removes everything between the end of the episode title and the file extension.

Any idea to improve it? I suppose there is a way to transform the first two dots with only one regex.
I believe `rename` is a GNU utility and therefore is not present on all Unix systems, I am looking for a more portable alternative.

Comment: If it works what is the problem? Why do you need to improve it, presumably once you run it you are done.

Comment: I am looking for something more portable no using `rename`.

Comment: Is `SXEY` invariable? Will it always be there in your files?

Comment: `rename` is not a GNU utility, it's a perl utility but yes, it isn't available for all systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appreciated that the question is actually about the `regex`, presented with the same I would avoid breaking my brain and

```
for m in *.mkv; 
    do echo mv $m "$(awk -F'.' '{
        printf "%s %s %s - %s - %s %s.%s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $(NF)}' <<<$m)";
done
```

Predictable, easy to read, and also easy to modify your output string. Just remove the `echo`

**EDIT**

Re your comment below about `sed`, you can use this same technique simply by processing your filename for output using `sed` instead of `awk`

```
for m in *.mkv; 
    do echo mv $m "$(sed 's/\./ /1;s/\./ /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ /1;s/\..*\././' <<<$m)";
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$ rename -n 's/.(S\d+E\d+)./ - $1 - /; s/\./ /g; s/\.1080p.+\././' *mkv
TV.Show.Title.SXEY.Episode.Title.1080p.Uploader.mkv -> TV Show Title - SXEY - Episode Title 1080p Uploader mkv
```

Or perhaps this:

```
$ rename -n 's/1080p.*\.//; s/\.(?!mkv)/ /g; s/S\d+E\d+/- $& -/' *mkv
TV.Show.Title.SXEY.Episode.Title.1080p.Uploader.mkv -> TV Show Title - SXEY - Episode Title.mkv
```

---

Note that there is no reason to escape the spaces. You could therefore simplify your command without actually changing anything in the regex logic:

```
rename 's/\./ - /;s/\./ - /;s/\.(?!mkv)/ /g;s/1080p.*(?=.mkv)//g' *.mkv
```

However, this adds a space before the `.mkv` (your original also did this) which you don't want. So maybe this instead:

```
rename -n 's/\./\ -\ /;s/\./\ -\ /;s/\.(?!mkv)/\ /g;s/ 1080p.*(?=.mkv)//g' *.mkv
```

---

If you want a more portable solution, you could just use `perl` directly (perl is available in almost, but not quite all, *nix systems):

```
perl -e 'for (@ARGV){$n=$_;s/1080p.*\.//;s/\.(?!mkv)/ /g;s/S\d+E\d+/- $& -/; rename($n,$_)}' *mkv
```

And for maximum portability, do the whole thing in the shell (with a tiny bit of `sed`):

```
for f in *mkv; do 
    k=${f//./ }
    k=$( printf '%s' "$k" | sed 's/S\([0-9][0-9]*E[0-9][0-9]\)/ - \1 -/')
    k=${k/ 1080p*/.mkv}
    mv -- "$f" "$k"
done
```

---

**Important note**: What you are trying to do is a very bad idea. Having spaces in your file names will just make your life harder and make any sort of operation you want to run on those files in the future more difficult. Please reconsider.

Comment: `SXEY` is not a constant, `X` and `Y` are numbers depending on the file.

Comment: @New2OB then please edit your question and explain that. We need to know what is constant and what can change in your file names.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, by the way, I like the maximum portability answer.
Don't worry I don't keep all the spaces in the filename. After doing this I set the title metadata form the filename and then I rename it again to a more easy to manipulate filename.

Comment: @New2OB ah, good to know! And you're very welcome. The updated answer should work for any `S01E12` type string.

Comment: @isaac you're quite right. I was thinking about how they cannot take things like `.*`, that aren't fixed length, and I got confused. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: @Isaac huh, so they do! I don't know what I was thinking of then. I know I've seen an error message about this and I had thought it meant I can only use fixed length strings in lookarounds, but I'm obviously wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rename -v -n \
  's/\./ /g;s/S[X0-9]*E[Y0-9]*/- $& -/;s/ \d*p .* mkv$/.mkv/' *.mkv
```

Output gives a trial run, showing what would happen, but not moving any files yet:

```
rename(TV.Show.Title.SXEY.Episode.Title.1080p.Uploader.mkv, 
       TV Show Title - SXEY - Episode Title.mkv)
```

If the output looks good remove `-v -n`.  Since the middle ***`s`****ubstitution* is my *ad hoc* method of coping with the unlikely demo string *"SXEY"*, (instead of *"S02E23"* or something), replace that with `s/S\d*E\d*/- $& -/`:

```
rename 's/\./ /g;s/S\d*E\d*/- $& -/;s/ \d*p .* mkv$/.mkv/' *.mkv
```

---

Notes:

- There's no need to escape spaces like so "`\`" when using single quotes "`' '`".
- The above code replaces all the `.`s with spaces, then hunts for the **S**eason/**E**pisode string, then restores the last file extension `.mkv`.  This avoids the need for fixed-length episode and show titles.

Comment: But maybe there's some `perl`y way of replacing all the spaces but the last one in one shot...

Answer (score 0):

you can use sed instead.

```
sed 's/\./ /1;s/\./ /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ /1;s/\.1080p\.Uploader\.mkv/\.mkv/1;'
```

it replaces the first occurrence of dot each time.

Comment: How about `sed 's/\./ /1;s/\./ /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ - /1;s/\./ /1;s/\..*\././'`

Comment: How can I rename using `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about whether capture groups are supported in your utility, but using them would be a viable strategy

```
([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)[.]([^.]+)
```

Then you would substitute with

```
$1 $2 $3 - $4 - $5 $6.$7
```

An advantage to this strategy is that it actually parses the semantic meaning of your other naming scheme and would allow fields to be reordered or omitted. I prefer using character groups to escape characters when possible, it is easier to read `[.]` than `\.`.